# Java sprite sheet rendering

Tags: java, rendering

So I have a sprite sheet for a 2d game I'm working on. As of right now, The map I have created works fine, but I realize that I want to change it so that the map is rendered at an angle (think diablo 1 & 2, or realm of the mad god) for more of a 3d feel.

If this question is too general, or more info is needed I can post my render methods or sprite sheet samples, but I was hoping that someone could give me an idea of how this is usually done? Do I have to re-create my sprite sheets so that they are angled, and THEN render them? Or can I keep my sprite sheet as is (it is in a format very similar to this image [HERE](http://img241.imageshack.us/img241/259/summersv6.png))

For clarity, I am not using OpenGL or anything similar. I have been writing the code from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but to turn 2D sprites into 2.5D sprites, you'll have to redo them. Keep in mind that they can include transparency as well.

Comment: Well, what's done is done. Time to open up paint.net.. Thanks for the answer sir.